# LCS too slow with large number of strings

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, gpu, dynamic-programming

I have a really big string list with about 40000 length, and I need to calculate the longest common sequence of each two of them. Is there any way to improve the program execution efficiency? Such as run the dp(dynamic programming) algorithm on gpu with python?

I have modified my program to be multi-process, but it still too slow.

Comment: you may get more help if you show the working code and small working sample. Recommendation questions are usually closed as too broad.

Comment: needs a lot more details!  e.g. what have you tried, and would be good to know the distribution of string lengths